# Annotation JCacheResult is not working in Infinispan and Glassfish 3.1.1

Tags: infinispan

I am trying to integrate JCache from Infinispan into my existing EJB project.

I have added Infinispan 5.0.1 CDI and Core packages to Maven pom.
Added Infinispan Interceptors in beans.xml and able to use the CacheResult annotation.

I am deploying the app in Glassfish 3.1.1. I have checked the Weld jar version, which is 
Module : org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle:1.1.1.Final

In the runtime, the CacheResult Method interceptor is not caching the method result and its always called.

My code looks like this,

```
public void cacheTest() {
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(
                this.getClass().getClassLoader());
        EmbeddedCacheManager manager = createCacheConfig();

        Set<String> cacheList = manager.getCacheNames(); // new
                                                            // DefaultCacheManager().getCacheNames();

        for (String cache : cacheList) {
            System.out.println("Cache name " + cache);
        }
        defaultCache = manager.getCache("test-cache");

        defaultCache.put("aa", "AA");
        String user = "User";

        greet(user);
        Set<String> keys = defaultCache.keySet();
        for (String key : keys) {
            System.out.println("Key is -" + key + "Value is -"
                    + defaultCache.get(key));
        } 

    }

    @CacheResult(cacheName = "test-cache")
    public String greet(@CacheKeyParam String user) {
        user += "Hello";
        return user;
    }

    public EmbeddedCacheManager createCacheConfig() {
        EmbeddedCacheManager manager = new DefaultCacheManager();
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.fluent().eviction().strategy(EvictionStrategy.FIFO).maxEntries(10)
                .expiration().maxIdle(1200000L).build();
        conf.fluent().clustering().sync();
         manager.start();
        manager.defineConfiguration("test-cache", conf);
        return manager;
    }
```

greet() method gets called but it will never add the method result to the test-cache. I feel am I missing some configuration or...I dont know. Please help me on this.

when I Inject the classes, they wont get constructed and they are null. The code is like this,

```
    @Inject
private static org.infinispan.Cache<String, String> defaultCache;

@Inject
private static EmbeddedCacheManager defaultCacheManager;
```

These gets executed without any error, but they wont get initialized.

I have no clue...But I am able to inject other EJBs with in this class easily. By the way I am trying to add Jcache functionality in one of EJBs.

I would appreciate your help...

Thanks...
Raj S

Answer (score 1):

Your *greet* method is in a CDI bean or in an EJB, right?

The cache defined in JCache annotations is looked up in the cache manager provided by Infinispan CDI. This cache manager contains the cache configured with CDI (for more information, see https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/CDI+Support). In your example the *test-cache* configuration will have no effect.

Another thing, if your *cacheTest* and *greet* methods are in the same class the *greet* method cannot be intercepted. If that's not the case maybe you're hitting [GLASSFISH-17184](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-17184).

For the Cache and EmbeddedCacheManager injections the problem is that you're doing a static injection, not supported by CDI. From CDI (JSR-299) specification

> An injected field is a non-static, non-final field of a bean class, or of any Java EE component class supporting injection.

If your method result is not cached, I think it's because the *CacheResultInterceptor* is not called. I've just made the test with the Infinispan CDI quickstart. If the interceptors are in a lib they are not enabled. I think it's a bug in Glassfish.

Btw, you can see an example of code in the Infinispan CDI quickstart [here](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-quickstart/tree/master/cdi).

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes,I am creating the Jcache in EJB only.I have removed the static for the Injected field and its complaining the following error -                                                                 SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [DefaultCacheManager] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private com.xxxx.xxxxx.xxx.CustomerFacade.defaultCacheManager]                   And the cache interceptors - I have packaged the Infinispan jars into EAr and deployed. Still my interceptors are not called...

Comment: For the test, can you try to unpack infinispan cdi classes inside your EJB project? (don't forget to add the META-INF/services folder and beans.xml). It seems that the extension is not active.

Comment: I am getting the same above exception that when deploying it says - Weld -001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for Cache

Comment: I am getting the following error for the CDI example   
No generic bean definition exists for interface                 `code` org.infinispan.cdi.Infinispan, but a generic producer does: [method] @GreetingCache @Infinispan @Produces public org.infinispan.quickstart.cdi.config.Config.greetingCache().I have kept the core and cdi packages from Infinispan available to the server.I am getting the above error when I am trying to deploy the code. Can you please give me some idea..abou what is wrong with this...